# How do use Github's builtin search functionality to search for issues closed by a github user?

Tags: github, github-api, issue-tracking

According to [this page](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues/), I'm able to search issues associated with a Github repo by author, assignee, mentioned user, and commenters. But I can't figure out how to search by issues that have been closed by a specific user. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible currently. If you're looking for a way to do this in a specific repository (and not across all of GitHub), a workaround would be to fetch the list of issues in the repository via the API and then filter them locally.

Comment: This is what I wound up doing. Thanks for the response.